# I am having issues around JS events when my pages load/refresh in my Heroku production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am having really weird issues regarding page loading and refresh events in my Heroku production environment.

For example when I initially go to the site, the home page loads correctly. I will navigate to another page, and then navigate back to the home site. This time JS events do not load. If I refresh the browser then they do load correctly.

Another example: When I first navigate to another page, a JS event does not load until I hit refresh.

I am not sure if this is a Heroku issue or a JS issues.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using rails 4 and/or turbolinks?

Comment: Turbolinks are the worst feature ever. There are about 5 billion rails devs on stackoverflow wondering why their apps behave weirdly because of it.

Comment: I am using rails 4/turbolinks. If I disable the gem is there another one you would recommend me using in place of it? I mean, what is the job it is performing anyways?

Comment: Alright I uninstalled turbolinks and it did resolve the issues I was having (thumbs up). However, I do understand the adjective was to make links on your site respond faster, obviously. Do you guys use any other gem successfully that achieves this?